# Draw a frame outside the sprite to produce a select effect in Cocos2D Android

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I have a view which can contain multiple sprites at a time, now i want to have a select effect when ever i touch a sprite. 
Some Usefull/helping links would be very helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways:

1. To change the sprite with selected version (make original sprite invisible and show selected).
2. Create a frame sprite (possibly from multiple parts (add them to one parent)) and show it when you need to select the original sprite.

**SOME CODE**

```
CCNode *base = [CCNode node];
CCSprite *original = [CCSprite node]; //change this to create your sprite
[base addChild:original]

CCNode *frameNode = [CCNode node];
[base addChild: frameNode];
[frameNode setVisible:NO];
CCSprite *part1 = [CCSprite node]; //replace to create your part
[frameNode addChild: part1];
[part1 setAnchorPoint:. ...];
[part1 setPosition: ...];
[part1 setRotation: ...];
//add more parts
```

When your original sprite is selected:

```
[frameNode setVisible: YES]; //you can also use some CCAction to make it appear more beautiful
```

Comment: hmmm... second one looks good but as i am a newbie in cocos, a little code would help a lot...

Comment: Ok thanx for the edit. but 2 issues: first i was talking about in android and second is, i dont think we can give custom width and height in setContentSize() because it just dont have any effect....

Comment: @Farhan: I've said nothing about setContentSize(). Did not notice 'andoroid'. I think you can easily rewrite this code for android

Comment: rewriting is what i have been doing since i started on cocos in android... anyways, actually, i cant have frame for every sprite, so i created a frame of 100x100 and was hoping to resize it to the selected sprite's size and then add it to layer...

Comment: @Farhan: to set the sprite size you can set it's scale: [sprite setScaleX: 100 / sprite.contentSize.width].

Comment: After scaling, if i get the size, it shows me same size as before scaling... do i have to do anything else??? i was reading somewhere about the use of updateTransform function, documentation says that it updates the quad after doing scaling/rotating etc... And much much thanx for your help

Comment: @Farhan: Write your own function to get the size: x = sprite.contentSize.width * sprite.scale.x

Comment: hmmm.. i guess we dont have anyother way... anyways much thanx.